# PHP javascript link id

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
//connect to database .... 
//select query .... 
if(isset($_GET["link"])==false){
echo "sample 1"; 
}else{
echo "sample 2" ;
} 
?>
<script type="javascript">
function Link(id)
{

location.href='linktest.php&link='+id;

}
</script>
<html>
<input type="button" value="link test" onclick="javascript: Link<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
</html>
```

(assumed question) How do I force the onclick event to contain the value of $row['id']?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the question in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not do anything with the value of `$row['id']`, you need to *display* it so you need to provide an `echo` statement.

Therefore, instead of,

```
onclick="javascript: Link<?php $row['id']; ?>
```

do this,

```
onclick="javascript: Link(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)
```

As commented, you also forgot parenthesis around the function call.

Comment: try `onclick="Link(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)"` without the javascript: it's not needed for onclick= and try doing `var Link = function(id) { ... }` instead of `function Link(id) { ... }`